# Pandas keep latest row update

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, row, data-cleaning

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like:

```py
     Contact  Amount Last updated
0  011000111       2   2023-01-01
1  011000111       2   2023-01-02
2  011000112       2   2023-01-03
3  011000112       2   2023-01-04
4  011000112       2   2023-01-06
5  011000111       2   2023-01-07
6  011000111       2   2023-01-09
7  011000111       3   2023-01-11
```

I want to keep the latest date in the `Last updated` column with each change to the combination of `Contact` and `Amount`. The expected dataframe should Look like:

```py
     Contact  Amount Last updated
1  011000111       2   2023-01-02
4  011000112       2   2023-01-06
6  011000111       2   2023-01-09
7  011000111       3   2023-01-11
```

This is what I currently have:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
data = {'Contact': ['011000111', '011000111', '011000112', '011000112', '011000112', '011000111', '011000111', '011000111'],
        'Amount': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        'Last updated': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-09', '2023-01-11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the "Last updated" column to a datetime type
df['Last updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last updated'])

# sort the dataframe by the "Contact" and "Last updated" columns in descending order
df = df.sort_values(['Last updated'], ascending=True)

# drop the duplicates based on the "Contact" column and keep the last occurrence
result = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Contact','Amount'], keep='last')

print(result)
```

which outputs:

```py
     Contact  Amount Last updated
4  011000112       2   2023-01-06
6  011000111       2   2023-01-09
7  011000111       3   2023-01-11
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Given your expected output, do you mean that you need the last update (i.e. the last row) for each combination of `Contact` and `Amount`. E.g. `(11000111, 2)` occurs both before and after `(11000112, 2)`. You need the last row for both of these sequences individually, correct?

Comment: @ouroboros1 the output he wants is selecting each row of `contact` based on `last updated`

Comment: @ouroboros1 Thank you. I am trying to keep a record of changes to the combination of `Contact` and `Amount`, keeping the latest `Last updated` value. 

Hence, although row 1 and row 5 have the values `(11000112, 2)`, they should both be present in the output.

Answer (score 3):

##### Annotated code

```
# compare current and prev row
c = ['Contact', 'Amount']
mask = df[c] != df[c].shift()

# Are the rows different?
mask = mask.any(axis=1)

# ensure the column is datetime type
df['Last updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last updated'])

# use cumsum to identify different blocks of same rows
# then group the dataframe and find the index of max value in last updated
result = df.loc[df.groupby(mask.cumsum())['Last updated'].idxmax()]
```

##### Result

```
     Contact Amount Last updated
1  011000111      2   2023-01-02
4  011000112      2   2023-01-06
6  011000111      2   2023-01-09
7  011000111      3   2023-01-11
```

Answer (score 0):

there should be four rows since there are two rows with Contact `011000111` with the last update of `2023-01-02`

this includes all rows with the recent `Last updated` for each `Contact`

```
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe
data = {'Contact': ['011000111', '011000111', '011000112', '011000112', '011000112', '011000111', '011000111', '011000111'],
        'Amount': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        'Last updated': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-09', '2023-01-11']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the "Last updated" column to a datetime type
df['Last updated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Last updated'])

# sort the dataframe by the "Contact" and "Last updated" columns in descending order
df = df.sort_values(['Contact', 'Last updated'], ascending=True)

# drop the duplicates based on the "Contact" column and keep the last occurrence
result = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Contact','Amount'], keep='last')

# keep all rows with the most recent 'Last updated' date for each unique 'Contact'
result = result.loc[result.groupby(['Contact','Amount'])['Last updated'].idxmax()].sort_values(['Last updated'])

print(result)
```

now what I did is drop all the duplicates that depends on `contact` and keep the last occurrence, those would let us have multiple same `contact` but with a different date for each one of them, to fix that we need to group the result from the dataframe by the `contact` we have and then have the `maximum` `last updated` for each group by using the `idxmax()` function.

This currently outputs the following dataframe which doesn't account for one of the rows.

```py
     Contact  Amount Last updated
4  011000112       2   2023-01-06
6  011000111       2   2023-01-09
7  011000111       3   2023-01-11
```

Comment: I have updated the question to capture essence of the question. Your answer was helpful but isn't the full answer I was looking for. Thank you for your answer! This is my first time using SO not I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.